# Leetcode Same Tree Iterative Solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

Question at hand: https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/

Can someone point out why my JavaScript solution can pass the test cases but fails during the actual submission?

```js
var isSameTree = function(p, q) {
  let queue = [];
  queue.push(p);
  queue.push(q);
  while (!queue.length) {
    let p = queue.shift();
    let q = queue.shift();

    if (p == null && q == null) {
      continue;
    } else if (p == null || q == null || p.val != q.val) {
      return false;
    } else {
      queue.push(p.left);
      queue.push(q.left);
      queue.push(p.right);
      queue.push(q.right);
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Essentially you need to traverse both trees. so you have to write your function recursively some way. your current implementation just checks the equality of trees' roots and nothing more.

Comment: But isn't that why I have this line in case the values do not match:

else if (p == null || q == null || p.val != q.val) {
      return false;
    }

Comment: Imagine both trees have a root with value of `3`. what happens next?

Comment: The `while` condition is such that it never gets into the loop. Typo... ;-)

Comment: Ah that's it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@trincot mentioned it in the comments.

Just update the comparison inside the while loop to get into that loop.

```js
var isSameTree = function(p, q) {
  let queue = [];
  queue.push(p);
  queue.push(q);
  while (queue.length != 0) {
    let p = queue.shift();
    let q = queue.shift();

    if (p == null && q == null) {
      continue;
    } else if (p == null || q == null || p.val != q.val) {
      return false;
    } else {
      queue.push(p.left);
      queue.push(q.left);
      queue.push(p.right);
      queue.push(q.right);
    }
  }
  console.log(queue);
  return true;
};
```

This will pass all the test cases.